# how to populate a schema not referenced inside it

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a blog and a comment schema. In the comment schema the blog Id is being referenced. Now I have a function that lists all the blogs when the index page loads and it gets it by doing Blog.findById(id).populate('user','username'). I want to also be able to populate all the comments this blog has but comments are not referenced inside the blog schema. I know that in the exec callback I can then do comment.find(blogid) but that is just tedious. I want to know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are not referencing the comments in the blog schema, there is no way you can populate it. `populate` is only used for fields present in the document. As you said, getting all the comments with the blog `_id` using `comment.find` in the callback of `Blog.findById` for the schema you are using is the way to go.

To make this process more efficient keep an `index` ([documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-index)) on the blogid field in the Comment collection. This will back the `comment.find({blogid:<some blogid>})` more efficient as indexed queries are super fast.